Decimals in x axis only showing 0s and not rounding properly in ApexCharts, also "stepSize" not working
I'm attempting to create a line graph that should show an x and y axis that are both numbers to the second decimal. Say I pass a min of 0.0345 and a max of 5.2345, I would expect the first number on the x axis to be 0.035 and the last number on the x axis to be 5.23, however it shows me 0.00 and 6.00, why is this happening?
here is the xaxis portion of my chart options:
        xaxis: {
          type: 'category',
          categories: [],
          min: this.min,
          max: this.max,
          stepSize: 0.5,
          title: {
            text: 'Label'
          },
          labels: {
            formatter: function (val) {
              return val.toFixed(2);
            }
          },
        }

Another thing that's happening is that the stepSize option doesn't do anything! I am trying to do steps by .5 but it still steps up by whole integers. Any idea why?
Can share whatever code is relevant, let me know

I FIGURED IT OUT!!! The type has to be set to numeric, found the answer in an old apexcharts bug report from 2021 LOL
